# Javascript put data on <template> and append it on tbody after axios request

Tags: javascript, html

I have here a table in which a person's data will be displayed

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th scope="col">Name</th>
             <th scope="col">Username</th>
             <th scope="col">Birthdate</th>
             <th scope="col">Age</th>
             <th scope="col">Email</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>

     <tbody>
          <!-- existing data could optionally be included here -->
     </tbody>
</table>
```

this template is will be use on putting the data and append it on the tbody

```
 <template id="persons">
       <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
 </template>
```

this is the JavaScript code that I have

```
let oCRUD = {

    init: function() {
        this.setDOMElements();
        this.getPersons();
    },

    // Setting DOM Elements
    setDOMElements: function() {
        this.oTemplate = document.querySelector('#persons'); //persons row
        this.oTbody =  document.querySelector("tbody");
        this.oClone = document.importNode(oCRUD.oTemplate.content, true);
        this.oTd = oCRUD.oClone.querySelectorAll("td");
    },

    getPersons: function() {
        axios.get('selectAll.php')
        .then(function (response) {
           response.data.forEach((element,index) => {
             oCRUD.oTd[0].textContent = element.name;
             oCRUD.oTd[1].textContent = element.username;
             oCRUD.oTd[2].textContent = element.birthdate;
             oCRUD.oTd[3].textContent = element.age;
             oCRUD.oTd[4].textContent = element.email;
             oCRUD.oTbody.appendChild(oCRUD.oClone);
        });

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}

// call the init function
oCRUD.init();
```

How can I use the template put the data there after the successful response of axios and append it on the tbody. This is my first time using DOM templating I have no idea how to start it.

This is the successful response after axios get request

```
[
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "john",
        username: "john doe",
        birthdate: "1999-05-21",
        age: "20",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "sally",
        username: "sally mcsalad",
        birthdate: "1999-03-27",
        age: "20",
        email: "try@gmail.com",
    },
]
```

EDIT: I SUCCESSFULLY SHOW THE DATA HOWEVER I ONLY GOT THE SECOND SET OF DATA (sally mcsalad) NOT THE WHOLE DATA

Comment: comment this line oCRUD.oTbody.appendChild(oCRUD.oClone); what will be your result?

Comment: no result .....

Comment: then you problem is you overwrite on the first person

Comment: how can i not overwrite it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is you only clone the node, and select the `td`s once. This counts as a single object, which will just update the existing elements on each iteration. You need to refresh the clone and the selected `td`s on each iteration

```js
var data = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "john",
        username: "john doe",
        birthdate: "1999-05-21",
        age: "20",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "sally",
        username: "sally mcsalad",
        birthdate: "1999-03-27",
        age: "20",
        email: "try@gmail.com",
    },
];

let oCRUD = {

    init: function() {
        this.setDOMElements();
        this.getPersons();
    },

    // Setting DOM Elements
    setDOMElements: function() {
        this.oTemplate = document.querySelector('#persons'); //persons row
        this.oTbody =  document.querySelector("tbody");
        this.oClone = document.importNode(oCRUD.oTemplate.content, true);
        this.oTd = oCRUD.oClone.querySelectorAll("td");
    },   
    
    refreshClone: function() {
      this.oClone = document.importNode(oCRUD.oTemplate.content, true);
      this.oTd = oCRUD.oClone.querySelectorAll("td");
    },

    getPersons: function() {
        /*axios.get('selectAll.php')
        .then(function (response) {*/
           data.forEach((element,index) => {
             
             oCRUD.refreshClone();
             oCRUD.oTd[0].textContent = element.name;
             oCRUD.oTd[1].textContent = element.username;
             oCRUD.oTd[2].textContent = element.birthdate;
             oCRUD.oTd[3].textContent = element.age;
             oCRUD.oTd[4].textContent = element.email;
             oCRUD.oTbody.appendChild(oCRUD.oClone);
        });

        /*})
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });*/
    }
}

// call the init function
oCRUD.init();
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th scope="col">Name</th>
             <th scope="col">Username</th>
             <th scope="col">Birthdate</th>
             <th scope="col">Age</th>
             <th scope="col">Email</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>

     <tbody>
          <!-- existing data could optionally be included here -->
     </tbody>
</table>


 <template id="persons">
       <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
 </template>
```

Comment: sir this is the follow up question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386589/refresh-table-after-a-successful-axios-post-request

Answer (score 0):

add the function generateTable to your code and call it after success your request

```js
function generateTable(persons){

 let oTbody =  document.querySelector("tbody");
       
        if(!persons) return;
        
        persons.forEach( person=>{
          let tr = 
          `<tr id=${person.id}>
                 <td>${person.name}</td>
                 <td>${person.username}</td>
                 <td>${person.birthday}</td>
                 <td>${person.age}</td>
                 <td>${person.email}</td>
           </tr>`
           oTbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tr);  
        })     
}

let persons =  [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "john",
        username: "john doe",
        birthdate: "1999-05-21",
        age: "20",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "sally",
        username: "sally mcsalad",
        birthdate: "1999-03-27",
        age: "20",
        email: "try@gmail.com",
    },
]

generateTable(persons)
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th scope="col">Name</th>
             <th scope="col">Username</th>
             <th scope="col">Birthdate</th>
             <th scope="col">Age</th>
             <th scope="col">Email</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>

     <tbody>
          <!-- existing data could optionally be included here -->
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it is it possible to use this on template tag?

Comment: you mean to wrap each tr by <template>

Comment: Do you want to show all person? how you would like your table looks like

Comment: I want to show all person. I manage to do that however i only the got the second set of data which is user sally mcsalad

Comment: I want to use the template tag. put the data there and append it to tbody

Comment: you need <template> all persons in between </temlate>

Comment: or each tr wrapped by template?

Comment: look at my approach on displaying the data. I want it to be like that however i just only get the second set of data overwriting the first person

Answer (score 0):

Use template function in general, such as [lodash.template](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template) or [jQuery.tmpl](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl), you can also implement a simple template function.

Step1: define a template function to transit each data object to html string.

```
# use ES2015 string template feature
function transitData(data){
  return '<tr>' +
         `<td class="record">${data.name}</td>` +
         `<td>${data.email}</td>` +
         '</tr>';
}
```

Step2: get Server response and render your data collection(such as array).

```
axios.get('selectAll.php').then(response => {
  let html = response.data.map(transitData).join("\n");
  oTbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
});
```